# Adding multiple variables, of a single datatype/class, to an ArrayList without singularly calling the .add method?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, arraylist

I currently have 40 unique threads in Java, all of which will carry out their own duties, however for each thread to start we need to call the .start() method.

In order to do this will incur an additional 40 statements, calling .start() on each thread, and it doesn't seem intuitive.

I wanted to add all 40 threads to an ArrayList and loop through it to call .start() on all threads. However, even just adding the threads to an ArrayList requires 40 additional statements, calling .add() to each thread.

I have tried some reflection techniques, to no avail (I am still a newbie programmer).

Is there a simple solution I am missing? Does Java not support this?

So my basic code so far follows this format:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LoadTest thread1 = new LoadTest(); //then this is repeated 40 times. 
    thread1.start(); //this is repeated 40 times.
}
```

Comment: @xerx593 to call the addAll() method, the LoadTest variables would already have to be part of some collection, would they not? In that case, I would still need to add a separate add() statement of sorts to each LoadTest. Please advise if this is not the case.

Comment: It's hard to write a program that truly does 40 different things without writing a _lot_ of lines of code. Each one of those 40 different threads must have its own unique thread function, right? That's got to be at least a few hundred lines of code right there. And then you had to write at least 40 different lines to create each thread, and more lines of code to create the parameters that are passed to each thread. It's kind of hard to imagine how you can avoid writing 40 `.start()` calls... \*IF\* the threads _truly are_ doing 40 different things.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Its plausible I make each of the 40 threads carry out the same functionality. Would this potentially lead to a solution of skipping the 40 .add()/.start() calls do you think?

Comment: If 40 threads all are running the same thread function, maybe with different parameters for each, then you almost certainly can create them and start them in a loop. Maybe the loop iterates over some collection of 40 different objects or "records" or "configurations" from which the parameters for the thread function are obtained.

Comment: Maybe the use of [executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) is appropriate for your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work this. Code implementation below. Thank you for your comments helping.

```
public static void doTest() throws InterruptedException
{
    //list to hold the threads
    ArrayList<LoadTest> threadList = new ArrayList<LoadTest>();
    //defining the number of threads 
    LoadTest[] objects = new LoadTest[40];
    //loop through the size of the LoadTest list and create a new thread
    for(int i = 0; i<objects.length; i++)
    {
        objects[i] = new LoadTest();
    }
    
    //add the load test to the ArrayList 
    for(LoadTest obj: objects)
    {
        if(obj.getClass() == LoadTest.class)
        {
            threadList.add(obj);
        }
    }
    //run all tests 
    for(LoadTest temp: threadList)
    {
        temp.start();
    }
    //seperate loop to ensure all tests run concurrently, but
    //programme prints execution time seperately
    for(LoadTest temp: threadList)
    {
        temp.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to start all your threads, and keep them in a list just to join on them afterwards, this is an alternative to do this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40);
CompletableFuture[] futures =
 IntStream.range(0, 40)          // a loop to 40 essentially
 .mapToObj(i -> new LoadTest())  // create a task in each 
 .map(lt -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(lt, executor)) // submit to a thread
 .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);  // collect all the threads
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
```

In general, directly creating a `Thread` and starting it is a somewhat obsolete means of concurrency in Java. The `ExecutorService` allows you to define a pool of threads your tasks will run in, giving you better control over how many threads actually run in parallel. `CompletableFuture` is a high level construct to easily manage concurrent processing pipelines.

Comment: How does directly calling `new Thread(...)` not give the programmer absolute control over how many threads are created? There are a couple of reasons why a programmer might want to use a thread pool (e.g., in your example, above, where it's the easiest way to get a `Future` for each thread.) But sometimes, all the programmer wants is a single, dedicated thread, and when that's the case, using a thread pool adds nothing of value to the program...

Comment: ...Though, If I was trying to write testable, re-useable code, I'd probably use a `ThreadFactory` to create the new, dedicated thread.

Comment: @SolomonSlow An example for a situation with less control is starting a thread for processing input from an external request, eg a controller. More generally, no class can guarantee it only starts "a single, dedicated thread" if this happens in a public method - except when it `join`s on it in the same context. But even in this case, using `new Thread(task).start().join()` has zero advantages over `CompletableFuture.runAsync(task).join()` (executor service or not).

Comment: Re, "starting a thread for...an external request..." I would absolutely use a thread pool for that. The case where I would use `new Thread(...)` (or, `threadFactory.newThread(...)`) is when the thread is started _once_ during initialization of the process, and it continues to run for the entire lifetime of the process. I've written a lot of those (especially, but not always, for embedded, real-time systems.)

Comment: P.S., I'll say again. Even if my program called `new Thread(r)` for each new request, _my code_ still would be in complete control of how many threads it created. If I wanted some policy that limited the number of concurrent requests, then I could write the code to implement it. \*But,\* in doing so, I would be re-inventing policies that already exist in classes like `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Your arguments will not convince me to _always_ use `ThreadPoolExecutor` (or, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`) but they _would_ convince me not to re-invent that wheel if it was what my application needed.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your task as `Runnable` rather than as a sub-class of `Thread`, this means you can use it with `Thread` or `ExecutorService`. If say you needed 10,000 instances later on, then a fixed sized thread pool `ExecutorService` or use of LOOM virtual threads would be preferred to something that `extends Thread`:

```
class LoadTest implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

You don't need a lot of code to kick off 40 instances, each in own named thread which might help if debugging or viewing stack traces:

```
List<Thread> tasks = IntStream.range(0, 40)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Thread(new LoadTest(), "MyThread-"+i))
        .peek(Thread::start)
        .toList();

// Wait for all to end
for(Thread t : tasks) {
    t.join();
}
```